# How to install other package version than default in buildroot?

Tags: embedded, buildroot

I need to use python3.7m instead of default python3.8 in my buildroot project. Is there a solution for that or only way is get older buildroot version?

Answer (score 3):

You do not have to downgrade Buildroot. You can always add a custom `python3` package based on an older version, e.g.: https://git.busybox.net/buildroot/tree/package/python3?id=b3424c8fc9d1199f5836483f15af48b56373609e

Here the documentation on how to add a package:
https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#adding-packages

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to add a custom package with a different python version, as @Ezra Bühler explained. However, that custom package must have a different name than `python3`, which means that you also need to make custom versions of all packages that use python3.

Therefore, a simpler possibility is to modify the Buildroot code itself. There's normally no need to go back to an older Buildroot version - instead, you can take just copy and overwrite python3 from an older version that still has python 3.7. Of course, this is a completely untested configuration so you might encounter some breakage, but it's usually doable. If you take that route, you'll want to also update python to the latest (currently python 3.7.11).